# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8000" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: django, ajax

I am currently building a website with Django and Javascript. I am working on the ajax calls that would the data needed for populate my homepage. However, I keep getting this cross-origin error. I have tried setting the document domain, enabling CROS headers  and passing CSRF tockens. All attempts have been unsuccessful. Please take a look at my javascript code above.

```
if (window.scrollY > news_elementTarget.offsetTop) {

            if (!news_fetched) {
              
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ajax/home',
                    type: 'get',

                    data: {
                        button_test: $(this).text(),
                        section: 'news',
                        CSRF: csrftoken,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log('success')
                        create_section_1(response.id, response.sections)
                        news_fetched = true
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to make an ajax call to the backend when the window scrolls to a certain div. The get request is never even sent to the backend. I really confused because I thought my domains are the same which wouldn't cause a Cross-origin error.

Comment: I dont think that this has to do with the ajax call to django backend - do you have a frame somewhere on the page and try to access elements inside?

Comment: Yes, I do. The weird thing about this error is that when I use click() event the data is fetched. However, when I use scroll() event I will get the "cross-origin" error.